# Maven to Eclipse Integration

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, m2eclipse

I got eclipse galileo which i wish to use for java ee development. But I am facing a problem as when i try to setup the Maven Integration for eclipse i get the following errors:-

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.2.2.20100217-2310 (epp.package.jee 1.2.2.20100217-2310)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Engine 1.0.102.R35x_v20091117 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 1.0.102.R35x_v20091117)
    Equinox Provisioning Engine 1.0.100.v20090525 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 1.0.100.v20090525)
    Equinox Provisioning Engine 1.0.101.R35x_v20090825 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 1.0.101.R35x_v20090825)
    Equinox Provisioning Engine 2.3.0.v20130526-2122 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 2.3.0.v20130526-2122)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.2.2.20100217-2310 (epp.package.jee 1.2.2.20100217-2310)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.2.2.20100217-2310]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.2.2.20100217-2310 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.2.2.20100217-2310)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e Marketplace 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.discovery 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.discovery [1.4.0.20130601-0317]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.5.2.M20100113-0800]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE UI 3.5.2.M20100113-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.5.2.M20100113-0800)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine [1.0.100,2.0.0)
```

Comment: Seems to me like you are trying to install maven integration for a version of Eclipse you are not using

Comment: Yes - as @codd mentioned - check you are using the correct install URL for the version of eclipse you are using.